# duplication of objects that are equal

Tags: python, oop, reference

I have two kinds of objects:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.name == other.name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
```

I have another object B defined with two objects A:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, objectA1, objectA2):
        self.objectA1 = objectA1
        self.objectA2 = objectA2
```

My problem is that, if I do:

```
a = A("name")
b = B(A("name"), A("other"))
```

Then the two A("name") are equal (according to the equal I defined) but not pointing to the same object: I have

```
b.objectA1 is a == False
```

Which is a problem because I want to access b.objectA1.x and b.objectA1.y, and I want them to be the x and y of a.

I know it's a reference issue, but I don't know how to fix it to have what I want, that is,

```
A("name") is A("name") == True
```

all the time, even when A is defined with B.

Precision: everything is defined from a tkinter interface, with strings.
I guess I could do a dictionnary d which keys are strings (the name of object A), and which values are the associated object A.
Then I would define:

```
b = B(d["s1"], d["s2"])
```

However, it seems ugly and I'm looking for the pythonic way to do (I'm not very familiar with OOP)

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use a factory for creating `A` instances instead of using the constructor directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to Python's OOP and things like metaclasses are a bit funny for you then accept tobias_k advice: use a factory. It can be simple function like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def factory(name, pool={}):
    if name not in pool:
        pool[name] = A(name)
    return pool[name]

a = factory("foo")
b = factory("bar")
c = factory("foo")

assert a is a
assert a is not b
assert a is c
```

Also, I just saw your comment about some more Pythonic way then storing objects in dictionary. Operator "is" compares id() return for two objects. In CPython it is unique for every object, not changing during object's lifetime. The best you can get is some way of storing instances somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I am not at all sure whether this is a great idea, but you could mess with the `__new__` method and check whether an instance with the same parameters has been created before:

```
class A(object):
    pool = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        key = tuple(args)
        if key not in A.pool:
            A.pool[key] = super(A, cls).__new__(cls)
        return A.pool[key]

    # rest is the same as in your class
```

Example:

```
>>> A("foo") is A("bar")
False
>>> A("foo") is A("foo")
True
```

Note that this *still* calls `__init__` for the objects retrieved from the `pool`, so those are initialized twice. Also, this will only work if the objects are immutable; if two instances are made equal *after* initialization, they remain different instances.

Comment: Thanks. It is similar to what I said in "precision" at the end of my post: make a dict that associates the object (value) to the name (key). But I wonder whether this is the "pythonic" way to do what I want.

Comment: @user5049567 Yes, it is similar in this regard, that is uses a dictionary. The point is that this way you do not have to worry about it. You just create instances just like you would normally and the `__new__` method takes care of preventing "duplicates".